# Remove quotes in the 'keys' section of a string in a string of key/value pairs

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove single quotes from the 'key' pairs in a string, but leave the single quotes in the value pair.

Each time the key/value options will be different so it needs to be generic. The only thing that will stay is the commas.

For example my original string is:

```
'Key'='Value', 'Key'='Value', 'Key'='Value', 'Key'='Value'
```

and my desired outcome is:

```
Key='Value', Key='Value', Key='Value', Key='Value'
```

Not sure how I would go about doing this in regex/Python. I've tried looping through regex matches and `re.sub` but to no avail.

Comment: Hello , please provide attempt so the community can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply capture the keys using,

```
'([^']+)'=
```

And replace it with `\1=`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/94wwYN/1)**

Python codes,

```
import re

s = "'Key'='Value', 'Key'='Value', 'Key'='Value', 'Key'='Value'"

print(re.sub(r"'([^']+)'=", r"\1=", s))
```

Prints the keys without quotes like you wanted,

```
Key='Value', Key='Value', Key='Value', Key='Value'
```